# How to add condensate drain to this small section of cast iron/PVC sewer line?

Tags: drain, sewer, condensate, sewer-gas

I am looking for a way to connect a condensate drain line (pump from HPWH and HP) to this sewer part:

[image]

The bottom part seems to be cast iron, the top part PVC. I do not know how they are connected.

If my understanding is right I may also need a p-trap. But there is not too much room. Is there a compact p-trap or a Y with p-trap ?

Since I do not have much experience yet with sewer line I’d appreciate if the answer is as detailed as possible (e.g., parts needed, how to disassemble the current line, how to put mate the new parts.

PS: The pipe that goes up is just the drain for the washer.

Comment: You're sure that's PVC and not ABS?

Comment: Your local area may or may not want condensate in the sewer at all. In areas with limited water they usually do, in areas with treatment capacity issues they don't like having clean water added to the waste stream to be processed.

Comment: @Huesmann I am not, I just assumed PVC but yes, ABS looks more correct.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Good point. I just looked up ordinance and it states "Air conditioning condensate may be discharged to the sanitary sewer or to permeable earth", so yes, it's allowed.